# Cannot convert the same type g++

Tags: c++, g++

I have this error at compilation with g++, ut it is the same type so i dont know what to do:

```
error: cannot convert ‘IOperand*’ to ‘IOperand Factory:: *’ in return
   68 |     return (tmp->retOperand(type, value));
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                            |
      |                            IOperand*
```

here is the code:

```
IOperand Factory::*retOperand(eOperandType type, const std::string &value)
{
    methodPtr_t mfPtr;
    std::map<eOperandType, methodPtr_t>::iterator it;
    return (NULL);
}

static IOperand Factory::*createOperand(eOperandType type, const std::string &value)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Factory> tmp = std::make_unique<Factory>();
    return (tmp->retOperand(type, value));
}
```

here is my header:

```
class Factory {
    public:
        Factory();
        ~Factory();
        static IOperand *createOperand(eOperandType type, const std::string &value);
        IOperand *retOperand(eOperandType type, const std::string &value);

    protected:

    private:
        using methodPtr_t = IOperand *(Factory::*)(const std::string &);

        IOperand *createInt8(const std::string &value);
        IOperand *createInt16(const std::string &value);
        IOperand *createInt32(const std::string &value);
        IOperand *createFloat(const std::string &value);
        IOperand *createDouble(const std::string &value);
        IOperand *createBigDecimal(const std::string &value);
        std::map<eOperandType, methodPtr_t> _methods;
};
```

Comment: In what way are those the same type?

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
IOperand* Factory::retOperand(eOperandType type, const std::string &value) { /*..*/}
//      ^          X
IOperand* Factory::createOperand(eOperandType type, const std::string &value) { /**/ }
//      ^          X
```

And

`IOperand*` is not the same as `IOperand Factory::*`: The former is simply a pointer on `IOperand`, the later is a member pointer (for class `Factory`, and member type should be `IOperand`).

Answer (score 1):

The `*` is in the wrong place in the implementations. Use

```
IOperand* Factory::retOperand(...)
{
...
}

static IOperand* Factory::createOperand(...)
{
....
}
```